# new TextView(this); не могу разобраться

Tags: java, android

Понадобилась функция программного создания текста. Не могу разобраться, как созданный текст переместить в уже заготовленный *RelativeLayout*.

Как тексту присвоить *alignComponent* и *alignParent*?

Не знаю даже, где прочитать про это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [этой статье](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/layout/relativelayout.php) описано как работать RelativeLoyout не через разметку.

Comment: Очень плохой пример, и очень маленький

Comment: А не разобрался, посмотрю

Comment: Там не сказано как сделать alignComponent

Comment: мне нужно обязательно left top!

Comment: Не очень понимаю вас. Добавьте xml разметку в вопрос какую вы хотите.

Comment: <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/button3" />

Comment: Вот эти танцы, layout_alignParentBottom как сделать

Comment: И потом это android:layout_above="@+id/button3"

Comment: Что-то не работает                     RelativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, 1891);

Comment: Спасибо сам разобрался